# rand() returns same number after rapid AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax, apache, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter controller in my application (`application/controllers/random_number.php`), which is supposed to generate a random number (`echo rand();`).

Now, the issue I'm having is that when I call an HTTP request to that controller, it seems that it only actually generates a new number every second or so, therefore returning the same number if I call multiple requests within that timeframe. If I run a for loop to echo multiple random numbers, `rand()` returns different numbers like it's supposed to (and returning the same set of numbers until a second or so has passed).

Why is it doing that, and what can I do to fix it?

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.3, PHP 5.5.12, and Apache/2.4.9 on Windows 7 Home Premium, 32-bit.

Edit: It's not a webpage caching issue. I've added a small segment where it saves the number to the DB, and it proves that it's the application that's doing that, not the browser.

http://puu.sh/deoWI/30cf5083e9.png

Comment: Thats because rand() is using time as seed. Try mt_rand()

Comment: I would add it as answer but my explanation is a bit to simple

Comment: No, that's fine. It fixed my issue, so it's a valid enough answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `rand()` relies on time as the seeding mechanism, therefore not generating a new random number quickly enough.

Use [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead.